# How to decorate app methods in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, decorator

I use node.js and express v4.12. I want to decorate all `app.get` calls by custom logic.

```
app.get(/*getPath*/, function (req, res, next) {
    // regular logic
});
```

and my custom logic

```
customFunc() {
 if (getPath === 'somePath' && req.headers.authorization === 'encoded user'){
       //costum logic goes here
       next();
    } else {
       res.sendStatus(403);
    }     
}
```

The idea is to execute custom logic before code that I already have but I need access to `req`, `res` and `next` objects inside my custom function. And another problem that I need to have app.get arguments to work with requested pattern inside custumFunc. 
I tried to implement decorator pattern just like this:

```
var testfunc = function() {
    console.log('decorated!');
};

var decorator = function(f, app_get) {
    f();
    return app_get.apply(this, arguments);
};
app.get = decorator(testfunc, app.get);
```

But javascript throws an error.

**EDIT**
In case `app.use()` I can only get req.path like `/users/22` but when I use it like `app.get('/users/:id', acl, cb)` I can get `req.route.path` property and it equals `'/users/:id'`and this is what I need for my ACL decorator. But I don't want to call `acl` function for each endpoint and try to move it to app.use() but whith `req.route.path` property.

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: there is lazyloader error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of implementing your [middleware](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html):

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
 if (req.path==='somePath' && req.headers.authorization ==='encoded user'){
       //costum logic goes here
       next();
    } else {
       res.sendStatus(403);
    }  
});
```

If you want to pass middleware only in one route you can implement like this:

```
app.get(/*getPath*/, customFunc, function (req, res, next) {
    // regular logic
});
```

Comment: there is a problem. when I use app.use() I can get only req.path property like '/users/22' but when I use it like app.get('/users/:id', acl, cb) I can get req.route.path that equals '/users/:id' and this property is that I need to extract for my ACL decorator. In case app.use() I need to work with resolving what pattern was used for current request.

Comment: and what should I do if I want use it for all routes and I need req.route.path property? (not req.path)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to build a [middleware](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html). Simply add your decorator to the application via `app.use`.